# C - reading unexpected character with getchar()

Tags: c, debugging, getchar

Now I'm taking C programming course, so I'm totally newbies about C.  I'm now getting headache because my code doesn't work the way I thought it should.

Here is my code that shows problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    printf("\n\nList of Paycodes:\n");
    printf("1 Manager\n");
    printf("2 Hourly worker\n");
    printf("3 Commission Worker\n");
    printf("4 Cook\n\n");

    bool cd=true;
    float weekmoney;
    char name[100];
    char code[10];
    int codeint;
    char cl;
    int cllen;
    char hw[5];
    int hwint;
    int salary=0;

    while(cd){
        printf("Enter employee name: ");
        fgets(name,100,stdin);
        name[strlen(name)-1]='\0'; // nk remove new line lepas user input
        printf("Enter employee\'s paycode: ");
        strcpy(code, "");
        fgets(code, 10, stdin);
        codeint = atoi(code);
        if(codeint > 4 || codeint <= 0){
            printf("\nPlease enter correct employee\'s paycode!\n\n");
            continue;
        }else if(codeint == 1){
            printf("%s\'s pay for this week (RM): 500.00\n\n", name);
        }else if(codeint == 2){
            printf("Enter hours work this week: ");
            fgets(hw, 5, stdin);
            hwint=atoi(hw);
            if(hwint > 12){
                hwint -= 12;
                salary += 500;
            }
            if(hwint > 0){
                for(int i=0;i < hwint;i++){
                    salary += 100;
                }
            }
            printf("%s\'s pay for this week (RM): %d\n\n", name, salary);
        }else if(codeint == 3){
            printf("Enter %s\'s this week sales (RM): ", name);
            scanf("%f",&weekmoney);
            printf("%s\'s pay for this week (RM): %.1f\n", name, (((5.7/100)*weekmoney)+250));
        }
        while(true){
            printf("Do you wish to continue? (Y = Yes, N = No): ");
            cl=getchar();
            getchar();
            if(tolower(cl) == 'y'){
                break;
            }else if(tolower(cl) == 'n'){
                cd=false;
                break;
            }else{
                printf("\nPlease enter correct value!\n\n");
                continue;
            }
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Here is the problem and explanation.

If my code running through this section of code

```
printf("Enter %s\'s this week sales (RM): ", name);
scanf("%f",&weekmoney);
printf("%s\'s pay for this week (RM): %.1f\n", name, (((5.7/100)*weekmoney)+250));
```

This code here

```
cl=getchar();
getchar();
if(tolower(cl) == 'y'){
    break;
}else if(tolower(cl) == 'n'){
    cd=false;
    break;
}else{
    printf("\nPlease enter correct value!\n\n");
    continue;
}
```

Will get an error, but if my code doesn't run through the problem section, it works well.
I've tried to find solution + debug for nearly an hour but still haven't found the correct solution to solve my problem.

Comment: Note that when debugging a problem like this, it can help to print out the characters that you are finding are 'wrong'.  For example, `printf("Got %d (%c)\n", cl, isprint(cl) ? cl : '.');` would print out the unexpected character, and seeing that it printed 10 (newline) would give you an idea about what the trouble is. You should also be checking for EOF (and return values from `scanf()`). You need to change in the type of `cl`; it should be an `int` to allow for accurate handling of EOF (because `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`, because it has to return every `char` value plus EOF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put getchar(); remove the new line buffer after scanf

so it will be like this

```
printf("Enter %s\'s this week sales (RM): ", name);
scanf("%f",&weekmoney);
getchar();
printf("%s\'s pay for this week (RM): %.1f\n\n", name, (((5.7/100)*weekmoney)+250));
```

Thanks Yu Hao for new line in buffer explanation. :D

Comment: This works as long as the user didn't type any spaces (or other characters) after the weekly sales value.  It is often better to use `fgets()` to read the line of input and then `sscanf()` to parse it.

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%f",&weekmoney);
```

Here, when you input a number, and press ENTER, `scanf` will process the number, but the new line is still in the buffer, and will be processed by the following `getchar`. You can use the following to match the `\n`.

```
scanf("%f%*[\n]", &weekmoney);
```

However, `scanf` has many problems, use other function like `fgets` when possible.

Comment: how can I avoid new line still in the buffer ?

Comment: your *[\n] doesnt work for me..
but, put getchar(); after scanf("%f",&weekmoney); work very well for me and it's solve my problem :D

Comment: Note that `%*[\n]` is a suppressed assignment scanset conversion specification; be careful with the `%`.